# Why doesn't Console.WriteLine print anything in Visual Studio with Run without Debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I made a new C# console application in Visual Studio 2015 and the line `Console.WriteLine("String");` works fine when I start debugging, but running without debugging returns a blank command prompt window. How do I print to the console using start without debugging?

Comment: Using Avast?  It turned viral 2 weeks ago, uninstall it.

Comment: Can you put the code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans Passant commented, it was exactly because of my antivirus Avast that the "Run without debugging" wouldn't display anything. I disabled its shields and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Console.WriteLine() works the same in Release and Debug mode.  It writes to standard output stdout.  If you are creating a console application you should see the output in either mode.

Debug.WriteLine() however; has a compiler directive around it - #if DEBUG - and will not be compiled into release code.

Comment: I know I should see the output, that's why I don't understand why I'm not seeing it.